# Use WMIC to query local administrator group members

Tags: windows, command, wmi, wmic

Does anyone know of a way to query members of the local admin group using WMIC (On a remote server)? I'm aware that this is possible through powershell and vbs, but I'm really looking for a command line only option (to be called from an internal PHP site).

I've tried the following

```
wmic /Node:"ComputerName" path win32_groupuser where (groupcomponent="win32_group.name=\"administrators\",domain=\"Domain\"")
```

but wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
wmic /Node:"ComputerName" path win32_groupuser where (groupcomponent="win32_group.name=\"administrators\",domain=\"Computername\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not going to work, you need to add the % on the ComputerName as its a variable

It should look like this

```
wmic /Node:"%ComputerName%" path win32_groupuser where (groupcomponent="win32_group.name=\"administrators\",domain=\"%ComputerName%\"")
```